# display popup when clicked on image using php

Tags: php

I am having a jpg image something like a plan map.When I click a particular part in the image,a popup should be shown with some details. How I can do this using PHP?

Comment: 17 questions, and none of them accepted? You want to do client side work on PHP, which is a server side scripting language??? You CAN'T do it in PHP, you should do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Please give me some idea

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to accept the answers.But the answers helped me alot.

Comment: Click on the tick below the vote counts on the left side of the answer.

Comment: @Rekha, You can visit your previous questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/334116/rekha?tab=questions and click the checkmark next to the answer which you feel best answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement this on jQuery . It is stylish too and works on all browsers . Take a look on this site :

http://gettopup.com/

or search on google jquery lightbox , see the demos.